# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayTabCardReaderViewController", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this weird error when importing a library called pay tabs

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayTabCardReaderViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Under build settings

Architectures:

Architecture Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Base SDK Latest IOS(8.4)

Build Active Architecture Only 
Debug Yes
Release No

Supported Platforms IOS
Valid Architectures armv7 arm64

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Ahh, isn't Xcode great ?

What I would recommend is this:  Click on your project in the left panel, then check your architecture settings in both the **Project** *and* the **Targets** sections.
 [image]

And if you have any third-party projects within your project, do the same for them aswell.

(I had to do this when building an Xcode project which used the [MapBox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/) library.  Annoyingly, you *do* need to check this setting in each of the various Build Settings tabs, otherwise Xcode will complain.)

Comment: Any idea about this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904002/undefined-symbol-objc-class-when-creating-ios-framework)?

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary with Libraries** Add your third party library to this. If you could not find your library, click **Add other**.

Comment: This answer was the one that got me on the right track

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the library path to Build Settings -> Libraries Search Path? Check at Build Settings -> Link Binary With Libraries that your library is added also.