# Can't use SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, sdwebimage

Xcode: Version 7.2

OS X: 10.10.5

---

I'm a newbie into iOS and trying to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) in Objective-C by following the official installation guide, but I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImageManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I downloaded the zip file and unzip-ed it, and added the file to my project.

Also, added a dependency "ImageIO.framework" and Linker Flag "-ObjC".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0CS.png)

I've already read these questions:

- [How to install SDWebImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303778/how-to-install-sdwebimage)
- [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: “_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayTabCardReaderViewController”, referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917994/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-paytabcardreaderviewcon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't download and unzip. This is really the most horrible way to do things. Use [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org), [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) or at least [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). The "unzip way" makes code harder to maintain: you cannot know which version you imported (when you go back to this project in a year), noone knows where is the reference. People will manually change the source files, so later you won't be able to update to the newer version without losing these changes. You also have to setup your project manually, which as it seems, is troublesome for you (and many others, don't worry). Easiest way to fix it? Use CocoaPods.

To do it, open console and type:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Close your project in Xcode. Open the path to your .xcodeproj in console. Type:

```
$ pod init
```

Open .podfile. Paste there `pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'`. In console type:

```
$ pod install
```

When it completes, open .xcodeworkspace. Everything should be working fine now.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I started to use CocoaPods. It works perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad it helped you. Your code quality goes ++ ;). If you've found it helpful, you can accept the answer.

Comment: In my case, I was using 4.0.0. Still the same error appears.

Comment: It is not a problem of library but of linking. You're not attaching it correctly. Please follow my answer and you should have it solved.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen due to framework not linked up correctly into the app.

**Simply try this steps:**

- Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries
- Click on + symbol & add it from the project
- Clean App & build again

Hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

`pod deintegrate` + `pod install` fixed it for me !!!