# Importing static library in swift project

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, xcode, static-libraries

Create a static library in objective c and c and trying to import in swift project. 
[followed this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215981/612854)

**Getting this error while building application**

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XYZ", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: Static library source]
[image: Library Search Paths][image: import paths]
Using:

**Xcode10.2**

**Swift 4.2**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "\_OBJC\_CLASS\_$\_PayTabCardReaderViewController", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917994/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-paytabcardreaderviewcon)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's do it from scratch step-by-step just to recall that it is possible (used Xcode 11.2, sorry - no 10.2, but I did this even before, so sure nothing changed since then)

1) Create new project form template

> iOS > Single View App > Sample (Swift/Storyboard) > Next > Create >
>   Build > Ok

[image: Initial settings]

2) Create static lib from template

> Project Navigator > Sample > Add Target > iOS > Static Library >
>   Calculator (Objective-C) > Finish

[image: add static lib]

3) Add something meaningful to `Calculator`

Update Calculator.h & Calculator.m with following ...

```
@interface Calculator : NSObject
+ (NSString *)calculatedValue;
@end

@implementation Calculator
+ (NSString *)calculatedValue {
    return @"1 + 1 = 5";
}
@end
```

> Switch active schema to Calculator > Build > Ok

4) (!!! Very important step) Prepare Swift-ObjC bridge in main target

I prefer that Xcode do this, so... switch back active schema to Sample app

> File > New > Cocoa Touch Class > Stub (Objective-C)

[image: stati lib creation]

> Next > (Make sure target is Sample checked) > Create

[image: bridge creation]

> Create Bridging Header (This is it! - actually internally it does
>   more) > Remove Stub.h/m (as they don't need for us)

5) Open Sample-Briding-Header.h and into it `#import "Calculator.h"`

6) Add library to main app target

> Project Navigator > Sample > Target Sample > General > Section
>   "Frameworks, Libraries... > + > select libCalculator.a

[image: static lib embed]

Actually, that's it - now it possible to use Objective-C classes from static library in main Swift-based application

7) Simple demo manipulations... create `UILabel` in `View Controller Scene` of `Main.storyboard` and create outlet to it in `ViewController.swift`, set string generated in library to `UILabel.text` property

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        results.text = Calculator.calculatedValue()
    }
}
```

8) Build & Run > OK (observe result of integration)

[image]