# Undefined symbol OBJC_CLASS_$ when creating iOS framework

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to build a iOS framework, to this, I'm using some dependencies and while building the framework project alone gives no error, when I install using CocoaPods in a demo app I get the following error `Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_DFPRequest`.

So this is what I have in the framework:

*Podfile*

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'mylib' do  
  pod 'PrebidMobile'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'
  pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK'
end
```

*MyLib.podspec*

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    ...

    s.platform      = :ios, "10.0"
    s.swift_version = '5.0'
    
    s.xcconfig = {
        :LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS => '$(inherited)',
        :OTHER_CFLAGS => '$(inherited)',
        :OTHER_LDFLAGS => '$(inherited)',
        :HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS => '$(inherited)',
        :FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS => '$(inherited)'
    }

    s.framework = [
      'CoreTelephony',
      'SystemConfiguration',
      'UIKit',
      'Foundation'
    ]
  
    s.subspec 'core' do |core|
      core.source_files = 'Source/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
    end

    s.dependency 'PrebidMobile'
    s.dependency 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    s.dependency 'mopub-ios-sdk'
    s.dependency 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK'

  end
```

*Banner.swift*

```
import UIKit
import PrebidMobile
import GoogleMobileAds
import MoPub

enum BannerFormat: Int {
    case html
    case vast
}

class BannerController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, MPAdViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var appBannerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var adServerLabel: UILabel!

    var bannerFormat: BannerFormat = .html
    var adServerName: String = ""

    private var adUnit: AdUnit!
    
    private let amRequest = DFPRequest()
    private var amBanner: DFPBannerView!
    
    private var mpBanner: MPAdView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        adServerLabel.text = adServerName
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        adUnit?.stopAutoRefresh()
    }

    func viewControllerForPresentingModalView() -> UIViewController! {
        return self
    }

}
```

Now in the appdemo, I have

*Podfile*

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'appdemo (iOS)' do
  pod 'MyLib', :git => 'https://...mylib.git'
end
```

So, just by running `pod install && pod update` and building the appdemo I already got the error.

Since running the framework alone works, what am I doing wrong here that installing the framework does not work?

> Ld
> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib/mylib.framework/mylib
> normal (in target 'mylib' from project 'Pods')
> cd /Users/user/appdemo/Pods
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk
> -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib
> -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib
> -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities
> -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PrebidMobile
> -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC
> -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mopub-ios-sdk
> -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb
> -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current
> -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7
> -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
> -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/Frameworks/Release
> -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/Frameworks/Release/UserMessagingPlatform.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7
> -F/Users/user/appdemo/Pods/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/Frameworks/Release/UserMessagingPlatform.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
> -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mylib.LinkFileList
> -install_name @rpath/mylib.framework/mylib -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks
> -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mylib_lto.o
> -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
> -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mylib.swiftmodule
> -framework AVFoundation -framework AdSupport -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework GoogleInteractiveMediaAds -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices
> -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework WebKit -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework WebKit -framework CoreTelephony -framework Foundation -framework MoPub -framework PrebidMobile -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign
> -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mylib_dependency_info.dat
> -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdemo-gmoqpiaozrywmeguhfldbwybeebb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib/mylib.framework/mylib
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_DFPRequest", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in Banner.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
> 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

> Since running the framework alone works

I'm not 100% sure I understand this; you can't "run" a framework alone. If you mean that the framework builds, that's not surprising; the missing symbol is from a different library, and that doesn't have to be resolved until your framework is eventually linked into an application.

> what am I doing wrong here that installing the framework does not work?

Hard to say for certain, but I'd bet that it might have something to do with your app's Podfile:

> pod 'MyLib', :git => 'https://...mylib.git'

The podspec for `MyLib` should be in the root directory of that repo, so check that the URL points to where you think it does, that `MyLib.podspec` is in the root of that repository, and that the podspec is correct.

Run `pod install` and then `pod update` (running them separately is a good idea when troubleshooting so that you know for certain which one produced any errors or other output). Open up your app's workspace and find the file that defines the `DFPRequest` class. If you can't find it, you'll need to dig deeper into your pods setup to figure out what the problem is. If you *do* find the file, then your pods setup is probably OK; instead, check your project configuration and make sure that the file is actually included in the target you're trying to build.

Comment: I meant that I'm able to build the framework alone, on Xcode builder. At the appdemo, after install the pod I can see the files from Xcode explorer (https://imgur.com/70osrI8). From the pods installed, I also can go to the definition (https://imgur.com/a/APmdlcJ). The files and dependencies seems to be there.